# can't install or-tools on mac 10.10

Tags: python, macos, osx-yosemite, pypi, or-tools

I'm trying to install Google's or-tools on mac 10.10 - https://code.google.com/p/or-tools/wiki/OrToolsWithPyPi .
I install using `python2.7 setup.py install --user` (tried also with sudo and without --user) but get the following when it goes to pypi to download the package:

```
.. Some other output ..
Installed /Users/Zach/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/ortools_examples-1.3549-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for ortools-examples==1.3549
Searching for ortools
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/ortools/
No local packages or download links found for ortools
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('ortools')
```

I noticed that it creates the directory `build/bdist.macosx-10.8-x86_64/egg` in order to build everything in but I'm running macosx 10.10. 
When looking in https://pypi.python.org/simple/ortools/ I can see a matching egg file for version 3549 but it's for macosx10.9, could that be the problem? Why does setup.py thinks I'm on 10.8?

Anyway, it might not be the problem, so any other help is very appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Former solution** (using `easy_install` and `egg` file)

I temporarily solve the problem of installing by installing or-tools using `easy-install` directly from the `egg` file (I use `easy-install` installed from  MacPorts). Here is how I install it.

```
sudo easy_install-2.7 https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/o/ortools/ortools-1.3853-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg#md5=f1f23b375652d40b9fbce682302e8dc8
```

Here is the link address for or-tools egg file that I use: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ortools/1.3853

It will give some warning but I can load `or-tools` in Python by using `import ortools` with no problem.

**New solution** (using `pip`)

I can now install `ortools` using `pip`. However, default `protobuf` version is 2.6.0 so I have to uninstall and reinstall new protobuf version that works with `ortools` (e.g. in this case, we will do 3.0.0b4).

```
pip install protobuf==3.0.0b4
pip install ortools
```

**Note** that `ortools` is only compatible with Python 2.6, 2.7, and 3.2 not 3.5 yet

Comment: I'm getting this issue on 10.10 too. Tried this answer but got an error: `No local packages or download links found for ortools==1.3853`. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Joeh. Yeah my solution is now obsolete since they didn't update ortools package on their sites (I'm having the same issue). I'm not sure where is the most recent ortools. I will get back to you if I found the solution.

Comment: I got it installed but honestly I can't figure out how! I'll let you know if I can recreate it. There is a newer OR Tools egg. Also check out [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/or-tools-discuss/17hsQJZhGrE/rQbQy7bNQcEJ), which may help.

Comment: @joeh I updated solution. Now, I can use `pip` to install `ortools`. You can try code snippet from this repository: https://github.com/daniel-acuna/reviewer_assignment/blob/master/reviewer_assignment_website/paper_reviewer_matcher/linear_programming.py

Answer (score 1):

Now or-tools support python 3.5 and python 3.6.
also please notice v6.6 will require protobuf 3.5

cf requirement https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/Dependencies.txt