# cannot use ortools from Google

Tags: python-2.7, or-tools

I installed or tools onto a macbook pro running Mavericks (10.9.5) as per [these directions](https://developers.google.com/optimization/docs/installing)

I did initially get the error described here: [can't install or-tools on mac 10.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26593497/cant-install-or-tools-on-mac-10-10/28592365#28592365)

and followed the recommendation using easy_install. yes I did get the error they describe but it seemed that or tools installed properly. Issuing

```
import ortools
```

at the python prompt did not generate an error.

Then I went to try one of the examples google provided (see first link above) and get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "examples/golomb8.py", line 26, in <module>
    from google.apputils import app
ImportError: No module named google.apputils
```

Obviously I missed something. Can someone enlighten me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue here is that the `google.apputils` module is separate from ortools and needs to be installed separately. You can check ortools is installed by running some other examples in the Google provided repo such as  `python examples/map.py` , or the [example in this repo](https://github.com/swanson/degenerate) and ensuring  `python optimize.py`  results in the expected NBA lineup (such was my original reason for looking into  `ortools`  :-)).

Comment: Can i use or tools on app engine

Comment: @GeorgeC. Try this command : `python3 -m pip install --upgrade --user ortools`  . I did it on gcp always free tier.